# Deleting faces messed up

Tags: modeling

I am modeling a Bus for a cartoon project. I am looking for a model some thing like that:
[image]

In my model, I want to get rid of the area showing in White color.

[image]

Making it glass will not help me as it will take too much additional light effects and extra rendering efforts.

When I tried to delete the White faces it end up with very bad result:

[image]

Please suggest some solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all in your modifier stack Mirror should be before Subsurface, and secondly, because of Subsurface, Edges are rounding up. You will need to use combination of Creases/Proximity Loops to harden them. If you want detailed answer you will need to upload your blend file.

Comment: Simplest solution might be to just make it transparent. Don't believe it will add render time as no bounces are calculated.

Comment: Thanks, Swapping the subsurface with mirror helped a lot :)

Comment: Can you please post this solution as answer, so that I can accept it correct?